# Increasing Spark Read and Parquet Conversion Performance for Gzipped Text File

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Use case: 
A> Have Text Gzipped files in AWS s3 location
B> Hive Table created on top of the file, to access the data from the file as Table
C> Using Spark Dataframe to read the table and converting into Parquet Data with Snappy Compression
D> Number of fields in the table is 25, which includes 2 partition columns. Data Type is String except for two fields which has Decimal as data type.

Used following Spark Option: --executor-memory 37G --executor-cores 5 --num-executors 20

Cluster Size - 10 Data Nodes of type r3.8xLarge

Found the number of vCores used in AWS EMR is always equal to the number of files, may be because gzip files are not splittable. Gzipped files are coming from different system and size of files are  around 8 GB.

Total Time taken is more than 2 hours for Parquet conversion for 6 files with total size 29.8GB.

Is there a way to improve the performance via Spark, using version 2.0.2?

Code Snippet:

val srcDF = spark.sql(stgQuery)
srcDF.write.partitionBy("data_date","batch_number").options(Map("compression"->"snappy","spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version"->"2","spark.speculation"->"false")).mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(finalPath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter how many nodes you ask for, or how many cores there are, if you have 6 files, six threads will be assigned to work on them. Try to do one of

- save in a splittable format (snappy)
- get the source to save their data is many smaller files
- do some incremental conversion into a new format as you go along (e.g a single spark-streaming core polling for new gzip files, then saving elsewhere into snappy files. Maybe try with AWS-Lambda as the trigger for this, to save dedicating a single VM to the task.

Comment: Thanks Steve, we are converting to Parquet with Snappy compression. But the conversion process itself taking nearly 2.5 hours and I was trying to find a way to expedite, as Source is not going to change sometime soon.

Comment: I am really surprised its taking that long. D/L a single file to your desktop, do the operation there, use that as the reference "time it should take" value. Try it different phases: CSV.gz -> CSV.snappy, then do CSV.snappy -> Parquet.snappy as the more parallel operation